# C# 8 Call default implementation from within concrete type

Tags: c#, .net, c#-8.0

Given the following `interface` with a default implementation:

```
public interface IState
{
    string Name => "Unknown";
}
```

And a concrete implementation as follows:

```
public class Demo: IState
{
    public void PrintName()
   { 
       Console.WriteLine(this.Name); // <-- this is invalid syntax
   }
}
```

Is it possible to call the default implementation from within the concrete type?

I've had a look through the documentation for [default implementations for C# 8.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/default-interface-methods)  and if the answer is there I cannot spot it.

Comment: Incidentally, to realize why this can't work as written (or at least why it would be a bad idea), consider `Demo` implementing multiple interfaces with `Name`, as well as its own `Name` member. `this.Name` can only unambiguously refer to a `Name` member present on `Demo` itself (possibly through a base class). Extended `base` syntax [is being considered, though](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/2337).

Comment: It is the same as on explicit interface definitions, since ever, you need to cast `this` to the interface type, there is no way around it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use it by casting `this` to the interface, and call the property on the result of the cast. It's as if the class implemented the property using explicit interface implementation. Here's a complete example that prints "Unknown":

```cs
using System;

public interface IState
{
    string Name => "Unknown";
}

public class Demo : IState
{
    public void PrintName()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(((IState) this).Name);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        new Demo().PrintName();
    }
}
```

Comment: @ZakkDiaz it's no different than explicit interface implementations, which exist since v1

Comment: @ZakkDiaz: I suspect Panagiotis read your comment as saying that you didn't know about default method implementations (which were introduced in C# 8) as opposed to explicitly interface implementations (which have been in C# 1). That's certainly how I read your comment.